# Safety when drilling walls in the house?

Tags: wiring, walls, pipe, safety, drill

I'm currently fitting CCTV around my house which requires lots of drilling with a rather large bit (25mm).

My question is regarding safety when drilling as i don't want to hit any wiring and or water pipes. I know you can buy detectors, but from what I've read they seem pretty unreliable and pointless as they only work about an inch deep, especially with my house being old and the interior walls being brick rather than board.

How can i best stay safe in this situation?
I need to drill several holes through the cavity and several on interior walls. So how best to do this and not hit wires/pipes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step one: Drill a small hole only as deep as the wallboard. Step two: Look in the hole.

Comment: It's not a wallboard, it's solid brick. I should have mentioned, this is a solid red brick built house inside and out, UK.